Creating an excel database that is automatically populated from powerquery Outlook link
I am theorising how to automate a current process which is very manual and open to human error.
We receive a standardised Email template into the Outlook inbox, where the key data changes, but the fields stay the same.
I have managed to use power query to populate an excel document, but this doesn't pull the main email body from my understanding.
Currently, we populate a mini database in Excel manually using the data supplied by the emails we receive.
I want to pull the data from the emails, and automatically fill the data into the database.
We have access to Python, excel and SQL at work, but Excel is the primary resource. I am curious if I am starting a project which is not possible with these packages, or if it is possible some guidance on where to start would be great!

Maybe try https://www.xelplus.com/import-outlook-to-excel-with-power-query/

Hello @DarrenBartrup-Cook, this has been the starting point of this process. I feel like what I am trying to do is possible, but I need guidance on how to do it. Thanks for the link!

You're on the right track. The email body exists in the query, but as-is it won't be loaded into an Excel spreadsheet because it's a record.
I recommend you make a new blank query called something like "fMineTheBody" and then use the Power Query Editor's "Advanced Editor" to replace the code with something like:
// change below line to "/*" to test it, change to "//*" to turn it into a function
//*
(row as record) as record =>
let
/*/
let
    row = [
        Body = [
            TextBody = "example text of email goes here!#(lf,tab)Status: Success#(lf,tab)Count: 4"
        ]
    ],
//*/
    TextBody = row[Body][TextBody]
in
    [
        Status = Text.BetweenDelimiters(TextBody, "#(tab)Status: ", "#(lf)"),
        Count = Number.From(Text.BetweenDelimiters(TextBody, "#(tab)Count: ", "#(lf)"))
    ]

Once that function works, in the PowerQuery Editor, you can right-click on YourEmailQuery that you have so far, click "Reference" to create a new query that starts from that point, and then click the Advanced Editor button in the ribbon to replace the code with:
let
    Source = YourEmailQuery,
    #"Added MinedBody" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "MinedBody", fMineTheBody)
in
    #"Added MinedBody"

and then you can expand that MinedBody column to add the "Success" and "Count" values per email!
